# Problem proving "p", "k" are limit point.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

Good night, i have problem with this exercises:

$A=\left\{ 1-\frac{1}{n}:n=1,2,\ldots\right\} $

I make this:

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)=1$$

---

Prove:
Be $p=1$ and $r>0$, let '$s$ see "$p$" is a limit point.
If $p$ is a limit point then: $A\cap\left\{ \left(p-r,p+r\right)-\left\{ p \right\} \right\} \neq\emptyset$

Ovbiously $p$ is a limit point but i cannot prove that...

---

$$B=\left\{ \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n :n=1,2,\ldots\right\}$$

I make this:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e\;$$

---

Prove: Be $k=e$ and $r>0$, let '$s$ see "$k$" be a limit point. If $k$ is a limit point then:$B\cap\{ (k-r,k+r)-\{ k\} \} \neq\emptyset$

But i cannot see $B\cap\{ (k-r,k+r)-\{ k\} \} \neq\emptyset$ Please, help.

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you are asking. To help the reader try to state very clearly *exactly* what you need to prove in the the body of the question itself.

Comment: Don't you mean $k=e $ is a limit point.  Not $k=1$?  1 *isn't* a limit point.

Comment: Yep @fleablood sorry.

Comment: @BernardWojcik I want to prove p, k are limit point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $A$:

Let $n$ be such that ${1\over n} < r$. Then

$$ A\cap\left\{ \left(p-r,p+r\right)-\left\{ p \right\} \right\} =A\cap\left\{ \left(1-r,1+r\right)-\left\{ 1 \right\} \right\} $$

contains $1-{1\over n}$ and is therefore not empty. Since $r$ was arbitrary it follows that $p=1$ is a limit point of $A$.

Try to do the same proof for $B$.

Comment: Rudy i'm use the Archimedian property, it's fine? (it's the second answer)

Comment: @Bvss12 If I understand your comment correctly then yes: such $n$ in my answer exists because of the [Archimedian property of the real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property#Ordered_fields).

Answer (score 1):

You need more than the fact that $A\cap\left\{ \left(p-r,p+r\right)-\left\{ p \right\} \right\} \neq\emptyset$. This only says that the sequence is eventually within the punctured neighborhoods of $p$. You need to show that is eventually *entirely* within said neighborhoods. In symbols, you need to show:

$\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\forall n>N$ you have $1-\frac{1}{n}\in\left\{ \left(p-r,p+r\right)-\left\{ p \right\} \right\}$.

The reason you need that *every* $n>N$ is within the neighborhood is because of examples like $a_n=(-1^n)\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$, which does not have a limit (as $n\rightarrow\infty$) because it has subsequences that converge to both $1$ and $-1$.

Other than that important detail, your approach is correct. Note that what you actually show in the course of the proof is the existence of a $N$ satisfying:

$\forall n>N$ that $1-\frac{1}{n}\in\left\{ \left(p-r,p+r\right)-\left\{ p \right\} \right\}$.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are confusing limit of a sequence with [limit point of a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point).

Comment: @RudytheReindeer: The ideas are very closely related (you are correct that I am describing the limit of sequence). If a point, $p$, is a limit point of a set $A$, then there exists a sequence of points in $A$ such that the limit of that sequence is $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Well i work in this:
For first

Consider the open neighborhood $B(1,r)$. By the archimedean property, there exists some $r ∈ N$ so that  $r>\frac{1}{n}$. Then $B(1,\frac{1}{r})\subset B(1,r)$ and $A\cap\left\{ \left(p-r,p+r\right)-\left\{ p\right\} \right\} \neq\phi$ Then p it's limit point.

I'm working in the two.

Comment: You're on the right track: in $B$ the points are $(1-{1\over n})^n$. So what you need is an $n$ such that $r > \left ( 1 - {1\over n}\right)^n $.